# Image Failed to upload

Tags: php, backend

I have a project and I am inserting an image of the product from my addCoffee.php. Whenever I click submit, it does not show in mysql db.

It says "Failed to upload image".

Here is my php code for addCoffee.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['coffee_name'])) {
    $upload_image = '';

    $coffee_image = $_FILES['coffee_image'] ?? null;
    $coffee_name = $_POST['coffee_name'];
    $coffee_price = $_POST['coffee_price'];
    $coffee_description = $_POST['coffee_description'];

    if ($coffee_image && $coffee_image['error'] == 0) {
        $coffee_imagefilename = $coffee_image['name'];
        $coffee_imagefiletemp = $coffee_image['tmp_name'];

        $coffee_filename_separate = explode('.', $coffee_imagefilename);
        $file_extension = strtolower(end($coffee_filename_separate));
        $extension = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'];

        if (in_array($file_extension, $extension)) {
            $upload_image = 'images/' . $coffee_imagefilename;
            if (!move_uploaded_file($coffee_imagefiletemp, $upload_image)) {
                // Handle file upload error
                echo "Failed to upload image.";
                exit;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($upload_image && $coffee_name && $coffee_price && $coffee_description) {
        // Using prepared statement to prevent SQL Injection
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `coffee` (coffee_name, coffee_price, coffee_description, coffee_image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sdss", $coffee_name, $coffee_price, $coffee_description, $upload_image);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        if ($result) {
            header("Location: productsDashboard.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "Failed to insert data into database.";
        }
    }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Add Coffee</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/addCoffee.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> <!-- Link to the separated CSS file -->
</head>
<body>

<?php include "../dashboard/dashboard-header.php" ?>

<div class="coffee-form-container">
  <div class="coffee-input-container">
    <h1 class="form-header">Add Coffee</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="input-container">
        <input class="input" type="text" id="coffeeName" name="coffee_name" required />
        <label class="label">Coffee Name</label>
      </div>

      <div class="input-container">
        <input class="input" type="number" id="coffeePrice" name="coffee_price" step="0.01" required />
        <label class="label">Coffee Price</label>
      </div>

      <div class="input-container">
        <input class="input" type="text" id="coffeeDescription" name="coffee_description" required />
        <label class="label">Coffee Description</label>
      </div>

      <div class="input-image-container">
      <label for="coffeeImage" class="label">
        <button id="fileButton">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M13.5 3H12H8C6.34315 3 5 4.34315 5 6V18C5 19.6569 6.34315 21 8 21H11M13.5 3L19 8.625M13.5 3V7.625C13.5 8.17728 13.9477 8.625 14.5 8.625H19M19 8.625V11.8125" stroke="#fffffff" stroke-width="2"></path>
            <path d="M17 15V18M17 21V18M17 18H14M17 18H20" stroke="#fffffff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
          </svg>
          Add Image
        </button>
      </label>
      <input class="input" type="file" id="coffeeImage" name="coffee_image" required onchange="updateFileName(this)" />
    </div>

      <div class="buttons-container">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit"></input>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="cancel" onclick="goBack()">Cancel</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    function goBack() {
        window.location.href = 'productsDashboard.php';
    }
</script>
<script>
  function updateFileName(input) {
  const fileName = input.files[0].name;
  const button = document.getElementById('fileButton');
  button.innerHTML = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M13.5 3H12H8C6.34315 3 5 4.34315 5 6V18C5 19.6569 6.34315 21 8 21H11M13.5 3L19 8.625M13.5 3V7.625C13.5 8.17728 13.9477 8.625 14.5 8.625H19M19 8.625V11.8125" stroke="#fffffff" stroke-width="2"></path>
                        <path d="M17 15V18M17 21V18M17 18H14M17 18H20" stroke="#fffffff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
                      </svg> ${fileName}`;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting it to also display the image but this is what im getting after pressing submit.

[failed to upload image prompt.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VEAa.png)

Comment: Open the console dev tools to see if the library provides a reason why it is refusing the upload. Then report back here with the detailed error message.

Comment: Please make sure that `images` directory is writable (so that image can be uploaded) - otherwise the `move_uploaded_file` statement will fail, triggering the `exit` statement and it terminates the script altogether (and so will not trigger the db insert statement)